# CXF - How can encrypt all fields in XML

Tags: web-services, encryption, cxf, des

I've to connected a webservice that need to receive all fields (less one) encryted with 3DES.

How can I do that with an inteceptor, I don't want to do it at business level because all methods have field encryption.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use WS-Security to encrypt parts of a JAX-WS request:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

WS-SecurityPolicy can also be used, and is more powerful as you can use regular expressions to define what you want to encrypt:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

If you have a JAX-RS service you can encrypt in CXF as well:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-xml-security.html

Colm.